# Why does this UPDATE result in a deadlock?

Tags: multithreading, oracle, database-deadlocks

I have a table called `unprocessed` that gets filled with rows around the clock. It looks something like this

```
CREATE TABLE unprocessed (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR2(10),
    qty INT,
    thread_id VARCHAR2(30)
);

-- This indexes NULL values in thread_id
CREATE INDEX unprocessed_thread_id ON unprocessed (thread_id, 1);
```

I have a multi threaded application whose job is to process a small portion of the rows in parallel. My current strategy is to launch a thread, find 1000 rows with a NULL `thread_id`, update those rows with the thread's uuid, process those rows and then delete those rows.

Here is the query that I'm using to find rows with null `thread_id` and then "lock" them with the thread's uuid. This query is failing with deadlocks.

```
UPDATE unprocessed
SET thread_id = :thread_id
WHERE 1=1
    AND id IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM unprocessed
        WHERE thread_id IS NULL
        LIMIT 1000
        -- I've tried FOR UPDATE with no success
    )
;

COMMIT;
```

I have isolated it to this query by disabling everything else except this query and launching a high number of threads in a short amount of time.

I would have thought that this particular DML would block all other instances of this DML as it runs, but that isn't the case.

---

My question is simply why does this DML cause a dead lock against other instances of this query? Why doesn't it block other instances of the same DML until it completes?

Incidentally, I would also be curious to know if there is a better way to go about this problem.

Comment: You are getting this error?  ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource.  Oracle never blocks selects.

Comment: `It looks something like` - please show *exact* structure of this table, not something that is *similar to*. Are there any foreing keys in this table ? Please also attach a deadlock trace file to the question.

Comment: Are you sure this is your code and you are running agains Oracle? LIMIT 1000 is not valid Oracle syntax.